# Ansible Windows how to prepend to system environment variable

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, ansible-2.x, prepend

I am trying to configure Ansible to install a Python package `cryptography` onto Windows 10. 
 This requires prepending to two environment variables:

```
C:\> set LIB=C:\OpenSSL-win64\lib;%LIB%
C:\> set INCLUDE=C:\OpenSSL-win64\include;%INCLUDE%
```

[`cryptography` docs on this](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-windows)

I would like to prepend to the environment variables using Ansible's [`win_environment`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/win_environment_module.html).

However, **I can't figure out how to prepend to an environment variable via `win_environment`.  Can you please help me out?**

---

**What I Have Tried**

I tried the following task:

```yaml
- name: Set OpenSSL environment variables - LIB
  win_environment:
    name: LIB
    level: machine
    state: present
    value: C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib;%LIB%
```

Unfortunately, Ansible tries to interpret `%LIB%` as a path, spitting out: `Invalid search path '%LIB%' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified.`

---

**Research**

[how to extend windows path variable using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162552/how-to-extend-windows-path-variable-using-ansible)

The OP here had the same issue, except just for the `Path` variable.  Here are my comments:

- My use case is not the `Path` environment variable.
- The current answers basically manually prepend to the path over several steps using `raw` and/or `register`.  I was hoping for something simpler.

---

**Versions**

```
ansible==2.8.3
cryptography==2.6.1
```

Comment: did you try to use the `environment` task parameter ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html. This should be added to your pip taks (or whatever ansible module you're using to install your python dep).

Comment: I did not know about the parameter `environment`, thank you @Zeitounator!  That solves my problem, in this case.  However, I am still interested in the above question, as I think prepending to an environment variable is useful.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zeitounator pointed out in the comments on the OP, one can use the [`environment`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) task parameter as a workaround in the `cryptography` installation case (thank you @Zeitounator for doing so).

```yaml
- name: PIP Install Requirements
  win_shell: .\venv\Scripts\pip3.8 install -r requirements.txt
  args:
    chdir: c:\directory
  environment:
    LIB: C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib
    INCLUDE: C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include
```

I am posting this answer here because I think the `environment` task parameter is a useful tool.

However, it represents a workaround for the original question.  Since I think this question is useful, I am still interested in better ways to use Ansible to prepend to Windows environment variables.

Comment: You should use the [`pip` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html) rather than firing the shell.

Comment: Documentation does not specify windows target are unsupported so It should. But why don't you try ?